# Styling multiple select menu options

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
option:active {
   color: red;
}

option:focus {
   color: green;
   background: green;
}

option:checked {
   color: yellow;
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
 <option>One</option>
 <option>Two</option>
 <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

I have tried so many times to change the style of this but couldn't and wasn't able by so many ways, nor active, focus, after, before worked, The hover effect works perfectly, But selected options and active selected options can't be changed at all

All i want to change is the [When you click its blue] and [After you click somewhere else its gray], How can i change these two colors only?

Answer (score 0):

```
     <select multiple>
     <option>One</option>
     <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>

option:not(:checked) { 
    background-color: yellow; 
    color:yellow;
}
option:not(:focus){
background-color:green;
color:green;
}
option:not(:active){
color:red;
}
```

May be this will work with you